# How can I replace some words in my text file by keywords provided in another file using python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python.
I have two files. one file contains text, the second contain keywords.Here is a sample of the keywords file :

```
Parental authority

Rights and Responsibilities

Health and Safety
```

I want my code to parse my text, and whenever he finds a derivation of one of the keywords, he would replace them with the keyword as it is in my file.

Exemple : if "healthy and safe" is found in the text, he would replace it with "Health and Safety" mentioned in the keywords file.

I already have a function "Vocabulary" that does the lemmatization: 
print(j --> Vocabulary[j]) would display a word and its derivations. Exemple :

Safety --> Safely, Safe

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import spacy
from itertools import product
import re

text = pd.read_csv(name_file, sep=';', header=None, index_col=0)
text.shape
for i in text.index:
  document = i.lower
    for j in vocabulary:
       for t in vocabulary[j]:
        document.replace(t,j)
```

As a result, I'm having the following error :

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I am not sure about indentation - usually you do one space not tab or 4 spaces?

Comment: Why is **text.shape** in code?

Answer (score 1):

Try `i.lower()`.

It might be that document is not a string, but a function at the time in which you call `document.replace(t, j)`

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems:

1)
`document = i.lower` - are you sure that about type of variable **i**? Most probably its int so you can't make lower() to **int**(notice that should be `i.lower()`).

2) **replace** method working only on **str** so var **document** definitely is not **str**.